# Sentence tokenization w/o relying on punctuations and capitalizations

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spacy, linguistics

Is there a possible approach for extracting sentences from paragraphs / sentence tokenization for paragraphs that doesn't have any punctuations and/or all lowercased? We have a specific need for being able to split paragraphs into sentences while expecting the worst case that paragraph inputted are improper.

Example:

`this is a sentence this is a sentence this is a sentence this is a sentence this is a sentence`
into
`["this is a sentence", "this is a sentence", "this is a sentence", "this is a sentence", "this is a sentence"]`

The sentence tokenizer that we have tried so far seems to rely on punctuations and true casing:
Using **nltk.sent_tokenize**
`"This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence"`
into
`['This is a sentence.', 'This is a sentence.', 'This is a sentence']`

Comment: Have you found a tool to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a hard problem, and you are likely better off trying to figure out how to deal with imperfect sentence segmentation. That said there are some ways you can deal with this.

You can try to train a sentence segmenter from scratch using a sequence labeller. The sentencizer in spaCy is one such model. This should be pretty easy to configure, but without punctuation or case I'm not sure how well it'd work.

The other thing you can do is use a parser that segments text into sentences. The spaCy parser does this, but its training data is properly cased and punctuated, so you'd need to train your own model to do this. You could use the output of the parser on normal sentences, with everything lower cased and punctuation removed, as training data. Normally this kind of training data is inferior to the original, but given your specific needs it should be easy to get at least.

Other possibilities involve using models to add punctuation and casing back, but in that case you run into issues that errors in the models will compound, so it's probably harder than predicting sentence boundaries directly.

Comment: They write in the [documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#sbd-senter): "The recall for the senter is typically slightly lower than for the parser, which is better at predicting sentence boundaries **when punctuation is not present**." How can they make this claim when they train on text with punctuation and the tool does not do anything at all when punctuation is not present?!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is to use a statistical classifier based on words that typically start or end sentences. This will not necessarily work in your example (I think only a full grammatical analysis would be able to identify sentence boundaries in that case), but you might get some way towards your goal.

Simply build a list of words that typically come at the beginning of a sentence. Words like *the* or *this* will probably be quite high on that list; count how many times the word occurs in your training text, and how many of these times it is at the beginning of a sentence. Then do the same for the end -- here you should never get *the*, as it cannot end a sentence in any but the most contrived examples.

With these two lists, go through your text and work out if you have a word that is likely to end a sentence followed by one that is likely to start one; if yes, you have a candidate for a potential sentence boundary. In your example, *this* would be likely to start a sentence, and *sentence* would be likely to be the sentence-final word. Obviously it depends on your data whether it works or not. If you're feeling adventurous, use parts-of-speech tags instead of the actual words; then your lists will be much shorter, and it should probably still work just as well.

However, you might find that you also get phrase boundaries (as each sentence will start with a phrase, and the end of the last phrase of a sentence will also coincide with the end of the sentence). It is hard to predict whether it will work without actually trying it out, but it should be quick and easy to implement and is better than nothing.